# cron.php run through server not with commandline

Tags: magento2

https://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-setting-up-the-cronjob-using-cpanel.html
My cron.php is in my pub folder
http://www..com/pub/cron.php
Do I have to edit this

I have tried to connect through ssh via putty but putty is giving me error
Any help will be appreciated 
Thanks

Comment: You need to set it from cPanel right?

Answer (score 0):

Adding cron from SSH:

Find the PHP binary and php.ini path

To display the path to your PHP binary, enter

```
which php
```

A sample result follows:

```
/usr/bin/php
```

Create the cron job

To create a cron job for the Magento file system owner, enter the following command as a user with root privileges:

```
crontab -u <Magento file system owner user name> -e
```

For example,

```
crontab -u magento_user -e
```

A text editor displays. (You might need to choose a text editor first.)

```
* * * * * <path to php binary> <magento install dir>/bin/magento cron:run | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> <magento install dir>/var/log/magento.cron.log
* * * * * <path to php binary> <magento install dir>/update/cron.php >> <magento install dir>/var/log/update.cron.log
* * * * * <path to php binary> <magento install dir>/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> <magento install dir>/var/log/setup.cron.log
```

Example:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/magento2/bin/magento cron:run | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> /var/www/magento2/var/log/magento.cron.log
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/magento2/update/cron.php >> /var/www/magento2/var/log/update.cron.log
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/magento2/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> /var/www/magento2/var/log/setup.cron.log
```

If you don't need logs :

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/magento2/bin/magento cron:run >/dev/null 2>&1
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/magento2/update/cron.php >/dev/null 2>&1
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/magento2/bin/magento setup:cron:run >/dev/null 2>&1
```

For cPanel check below mentioned screenshot.

https://www.amanweb.in/stackexchange/cpanel-cron.jpg

You can also check document provided by magento for setting magento 2 cron.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html

Comment: I saw your screenshot

Comment: what command can i put ?

Comment: I haven't got access to my ssh somehow i  tried putty cygwin

Comment: I WANT TO KNOW IF I HAVE TO EDIT THIS FILE HOW CAN I EDIT THIS WHERE TO PUT COMMAND PATH IN THIS FILE http://www..com/pub/cron.php Do I have to edit this I AM USING MAGENTO 2.1.7

Comment: you have ssh access only set cron job

Comment: You want to use cron from cPanel right then you can just enter `<path to php binary> <magento install dir>/update/cron.php >/dev/null 2>&1`